# Single sign on wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I use single sign on with shibboleth and identity server. I always seem to run into authorization issues when logging in. When I add login permissions to the internal/everyone role, users can login in, but I don't want all users to login in. So I have a secondary user store added and only want specific roles to be allowed to login. No matter what permissions I add to the roles it doesn't do anything for single sign on. Do I have to add role mapping to the Service providers or the identity provider? I tried many things, and its always a problem I run into.

Comment: AFAIK, we don't check permission for Single Sign On. I would like some more details on your use case. So what you basically want is to restrict SSO based on user roles?

Comment: So I have a read only secondary userstore configured in carbon management. The I added permissions to login and create APIs to only two of those roles, but even though the roles had permission, WSO2 wouldn't allow logins/publish APIs. Our login page is connected to shibboleth and CAS. That's how the user logs in. So I only wanted people who had one of those two specific roles to be able to use the store and publisher. I got it working. Though I don't know if it is the proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under user-mgt.xml I changed this tag to true.

`<Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">true</Property>`

Change this tag in the APIM and gatways where I have my secondary user store connected. If your APIM is checking permissions remotely you can change the tag in the identity server.